# Android Bluetooth targeting SDK=32 working on Android 11 device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm a beginner in android developing and I'm actually trying to develop an application which read data from a BLE glucometer. My question is: can same application, when targeting sdk 32, work also on device who has android 11 or lower? When writing the code, I see that most of functions need BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission, which is not possible to be granted dinamically with device running on Android 11 or lower
Here are some snippets:

```
compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.biosys.mcinble"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
```

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(m_context, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        requestPermissionLauncher.launch(android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN);
                        return;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(m_context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        String[] neededPermissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, neededPermissions, REQUEST_FINEACCESS_PERMISSION);
                        return;
                    }
                }
```

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> enableBLERequest_launcher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    //interrompi operazione
                    if (mbScanning)
                        scanLeDevice(false);
                    else
                        mProgresBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    //abilitato, vai libero
                    if (!mbScanning && mBluetoothLeScanner != null)
                        scanLeDevice(true);
                    else
                        mProgresBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
    );

    private final ActivityResultLauncher<String> requestPermissionLauncher =
            registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(), isGranted -> {
                if (isGranted) {
                    Log.d("MAIN", "Permesso dato");
                } else {
                    // Explain to the user that the feature is unavailable because the
                    // feature requires a permission that the user has denied. At the
                    // same time, respect the user's decision. Don't link to system
                    // settings in an effort to convince the user to change their
                    // decision.
                    Log.d("MAIN", "Permesso NON dato");
                }
            });
```

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_FINEACCESS_PERMISSION:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(m_context, "PERMESSO FINEACCESS ACCORDATO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(m_context, "PERMESSO FINEACCESS NEGATO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

```
private void scanLeDevice(boolean bStart) {
    if (bStart) {
        // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
        mHandlerScanBLE.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mbScanning = false;
                mProgresBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(m_context, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Toast.makeText(m_context, m_context.getResources().getString(R.string.ble_permission_missing), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    mBluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(mBleScanCallback);
                } else {
                    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                }

            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(m_context, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(m_context, m_context.getResources().getString(R.string.ble_permission_missing), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(mBleScanCallback);
        } else {
            mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }
        Log.d("MAIN", "START SCANNING...");
        mbScanning = true;

    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            mBluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(mBleScanCallback);
        } else {
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }


        mbScanning = false;
        mProgresBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}

private final ScanCallback mBleScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        Toast.makeText(m_context, "scanning...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
    }
};

private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
        new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                if(device.getAddress().equalsIgnoreCase("94:e3:6d:6c:65:8d"))
                {
                    scanLeDevice(false);
                    Toast.makeText(m_context,device.getAddress(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        };
```

```
 <!-- Request legacy Bluetooth permissions on older devices. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
    android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
    android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"
    android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation"
    tools:targetApi="s" />



<!-- non ho capito se ci vuole o no-->
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />


<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
```

From what I saw, it is possible to access only to device address. Any other fucntion, expecially all the ones related to connection through BluetoothGatt, need to ask BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission, but if I try to achieve this on a device running on Android 11, permission window is obviously not prompted and permission is refused

### ********* EDIT 17/03/2023 ***************

Considering answer by Emil, I add this example to explain better the question.
If you try to ask for device name, android studio impose to add check for permission as follows:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(m_context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
                String sDevicename = device.getName();
```

When running app on android 11, you always have return, and it is not possible to ask for BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission, because if you try to handle such case in onRequestPermissionsResult, windows is not prompted and result is always NOT_GRANTED. Any funcion of BluetoothGatt is subjected to same permission check, so I wonder how such kind of app can manage simultaneously device with android 11 and device with android 12 (to whom is compiled for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android <= 11, it is enough with `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />` in order to get access to use the BluetoothGatt methods. You don't need any permission window, so you can just go ahead and use this functionality directly, on those devices.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this does not solve my problem, since I already added those permission as you can see in the code snippet. I'll edit my question to explani better

Comment: Don't rely too much on Android Studio suggestions. You can use `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {` to only perform the runtime permission check on Android >= 12 and skip the permission check for earlier Android versions and in that case just go ahead and use the API functions directly.

Comment: Here is an example how you can do different tests for Bluetooth permissions depending on Android version: https://github.com/50ButtonsEach/flic2lib-android-sample/blob/726006b45b37c1a17a170b5d007777683187dc3f/app/src/main/java/flic/io/flic2androidsample/MainActivity.java#L250

Comment: Thank you Emil. I tried not relying to Android Studio suggestion, but if a try to call, for example, device.getName() omitting permission check I always get null on Android 11 device, and I know for sure that my glucometer has a name, since I already developed a similar Qt based application for PC. My problem, actually, is not how to ask permission (but thank you for the example you sent), my problem is that the application I'm writing does not work running on Andorid 11 device

Comment: The name is retrieved immediately from a cache. If there is no name in the cache, or for example Bluetooth is turned off, `null` will be returned. If you are not allowed to get the name due to a permission you don't have, then a `SecurityException` will be thrown instead.

Comment: Spurred on by Emil's suggestions, I keep on writing the application, forgetting the device.getName problem for a while. Actually the suggestion about not relying on Android Studio suggestions is absolutely valid, since all Gatt functions work correctly on device running with Android 11. Thus, I removed every unnecessary call for BLUETOOTH_CONNECT (obviously when running on Android <= 11) and I've been able to get data from the glucometer. Since I'm a beginner, it was natural for me to accept every suggestion from the IDE...I will remember to interpret them correctly! Thank you again Emil!